# Random walk and variance

Tags: variance, lags, random-walk

If yt is pure random walk the variance Var(yt-yt-k) will (increase, decrease or remains constant) as lag k increases?

Comment: Please search our site: it's faster and more informative than waiting for answers.  https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=variance+random+walk.

Comment: I looked into them, but couldn't find it.

Comment: Does Var(yt-yt-k) mean $\text{Var}(y_t-y_{t-k})$?